# API work but return Instance of class name

Tags: list, api, flutter, dart, instance

I have this Api, 
printing the item oneJalsah is correct, but I have a problem when I return List, I get in the console
 ALL = [Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime', Instance of 'JalsahTime']

here is my cod

```
class Day1API{
  Future<List<JalsahTime>> getDay1()async{

    String url = "http://www.something.......";
    JalsahTime oneJalsah;
    List<JalsahTime> allJalsay =  List<JalsahTime>();
        print(url);
    var response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200){
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(data);
      for (var item in data){
        print("item = $item");
        oneJalsah = JalsahTime(item['id'], item['day'], item['start'], item['end'], item['date'], item['stateDay'], item['stateTime']);
        allJalsay.add(oneJalsah);
      }
      print("ALL = $allJalsay");
      print('jalsah done');
      return allJalsay;
    }
    else print(" day failed");
  }
}
```

here is my class

```
class JalsahTime{
  String id,day,start,end,date,stateDay,stateTime;
  JalsahTime(this.id, this.day, this.start, this.end, this.date, this.stateDay,
      this.stateTime);
}
```

Comment: implement `JalsahTime.toString()` method

Comment: but it is not string, it is list of class

Comment: you have `JalsahTime` class, right? i assume it is you pwn class (not from any package), so add inside that class [toString](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Object/toString.html) method

Comment: I Edit the question to add my class

Comment: all you have to do is to add [toString()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Object/toString.html) method in your class

Comment: *Instance* not class. You just have to implement toString of its class.

Answer (score 1):

Add `toString` method to your class

```
class JalsahTime{
  String id,day,start,end,date,stateDay,stateTime;
  JalsahTime(this.id, this.day, this.start, this.end, this.date, this.stateDay,
      this.stateTime);

  @override
  String toString(){
      return "Some representation of that instance: ${this.id}"   
  }
}
```

Comment: what about the others variables ? ,day,start,end,date,stateDay,stateTime;?

Comment: You need to add them to the string.